# Sort data on repeat sequence

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I want to order the data of my spread sheet on a repeat sequence

Actual
a a a b b b c c c

Desired
a b c a b c a b c

Any suggestions are much appreciated

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  What is a a a b b b c c c ( Values in one cell? values in separate cells?  column references?)  Are these the actual values (Are all a's, b's, and c's identical values or do these refer to positions?)  What is being reordered (Those actual values?  the contents of cells the values refer to?  Single cells, or collections of cells associated with those values?)  Do those values need to be reordered in place or can you produce separate output of the reordered values?  A screenshot might be useful.

Comment: All right, those are identical values on a single column, and I need to order them on a specific sequence for a production schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Under a a a b b b c c c write 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 and try sorting by row in **Custom Sort** click on options and choose **Sort Left to Write** in Sort by choose the row where you wrote 1 2 3 **Smallest to Largest** you will get your order.